# Where to find a shower half-panel?

Tags: bathroom, water, repair, shower, leak

my shower is 20 years old and leaking from the rubber around the glass.  We've tried to patch it a few times, but I'd like to just rip it off and put on a new one at this point.  The width seems to be a standard size, but it's this half-wall-side-panel that is impossible to find.

I've tried searching 'buttress', 'side panel', and quite a few other variations.

I highly doubt this is a custom shower, since everyone in the neighborhood has one that is similar.

Any thoughts or recommendations on what I should be searching for??
Do I need someone to custom make this panel?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It might not have been a custom shower for your house but the builder probably had a bunch custom made for the homes he was building. If I were you, I'd remove that panel and bring it to a shower repair shop or a glass and mirror shop that does showers and have them re seal it with a new rubber strip. They could even sell you the rubber strip and you could do it yourself. That glass is expensive and trying to get a custom made one will be difficult in getting the frame to match so you could re install it.

Comment: The rubber packing for the edges should be available from a good custom glass shop. It's probably just hardened up so it's not sealing any more.